# Not work onchange() insted of keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Problem:** 
Keyup() call ajax many time key by key but instead of i have used onChange() but it not worked.

**CODE for Email check in DB is already exist or not**

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#email").keyup(function() {

        var name = jQuery("#email").val();

        if (name == "") {
            jQuery("#disp").html("");
        } else {

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "user_check.php",
                data: "name=" + name,
                success: function(html) {

                    jQuery("#disp").html(html);

                }
            });
            return false;
        }

    });

});
```

can you give me suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Onchange work after lost focus.

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. Besides that, always pass an object for `data`: `data: {name: name}` - otherwise *you* must take care of urlencoding the value!

Answer (score 1):

[**Check Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3QEmX/). Onchange work after lost focus.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="a"/>
<input type="text" id="b"/>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#a").keypress(function(){
        console.log("keyPress");
    });
    $("#b").change(function(){
        console.log("Change");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533260/amit-agrawal) rightly mentioned in the comments "The `OnChange()` event works after focus is lost. "

Since you are making an ajax call, where you are posting some data to the server, `onChange()` event should ideally be used, and will be triggered only when focus is lost on that field.

You could check out the "keyUp" event otherwise.

- [onChange Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)
- [onKeyUp Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                $("#email").keyup(function(){

                    var name = $("#email").val();

                    if(name=="")
                    {
                                $("#disp").html("");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                                $.ajax({
                                    type:   "POST",
                                    url:    "user_check.php",
                                    data:   "name="+ name,
                                    success:    function(html){

                                        $("#disp").html(html);

                                        }
                                    });
                                    return false;
                    }

                });

        });
```